# To pivot in Python using user inputs generated from Streamlit

Tags: python, pivot-table

I am trying to build an app using Streamlit and currently facing obstacle while trying to recreate the field list of Excel, I am attaching the screenshot [Field List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDdmR.png), of how the table is supposed to look like [Data Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fdRJ.png).

I have managed to recreate the dataset from where the pivot needs to be taken, but I'm currently facing problem to create the same in Python.

Because I am using `streamlit`, it is supposed to take whatever input user chooses to give rather than hardcode the variables.

```py
col_list=['focus','category']

piv=pd.pivot_table(other_df,index=[col_list],columns=['Data_Period'],aggfunc='sum')
```

is throwing this error:

> ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

but this works:

```py
piv=pd.pivot_table(other_df,index=['focus','category'],columns=['Data_Period'],aggfunc='sum')
```

But the idea is to avoid any kind of hardcoding, how can I achieve this?

Comment: By doing index=[col_list], you are creating a list of list, try simply: index=col_list .

Comment: Thank you for that, it worked. However, could you help me with achieving the pivot table replicating that of the Excel screenshot I have shared?